# Question on using docker secrets and environments with an existing image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rstudio, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

I've been struggling with this concept. To start I'm new to docker and self teaching myself (slowly). I am using a docker swarm instance and trying to leverage docker secrets for a simple username and password to an exiting rocker/rstudio image. I've set up the reverse proxy and can successfully use https to access the R studio via my browser. Now when I pass the variables at path /run/secrets/user and /run/secrets/pass to the environment variables it doesn't work. Its essentially think the path is the actual username and password. I need the environment variables to actually pull the values (in this case user=test, pass=test123 as set up using the docker secret command). I've looked around and a bit of a loss on how to accomplish this. I know some have mentioned leveraging a custom entrypoint shell script and I'm a bit confused on how to do this. Here is what I've tried

1. Rebuild a brand new image using the existing r image with a dockerfile that adds entrypoint.sh to the image -> it can't find the entrypoint.sh doc
2. added entrypoint: entrypoint.sh as a part of my docker compose. Same issue.

I'm trying to use docker stack to build the containers. The stack gets built but the containers keep restarting to the point they are unusable.

Here are my files

Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/rstudio
COPY entry.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entry.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entry.sh"]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.3'

secrets:
  user:
    external: true
  pass:
    external: true

services:
  rserver:
    container_name: rstudio
    image: rocker/rstudio:latest (<-- this is the output of the build using rocker/rstudio and Dockerfile)
    secrets:
      - user
      - pass
    environment:
      - USER=/run/secrets/user
      - PASSWORD=/run/secrets/pass
    volumes:
      - ./rstudio:/home/user/rstudio
    ports:
      - 8787:8787
    restart: always
    entrypoint: /entry.sh
```

Finally here is the entry.sh file that I found on another thread

```
#get your envs files and export envars
export $(egrep  -v '^#'  /run/secrets/* | xargs) 
#if you need some specific file, where password is the secret name 
#export $(egrep  -v '^#'  /run/secrets/password| xargs) 
#call the dockerfile's entrypoint
source /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

In the end it would be great to use my secret user and pass and pass those to the environment variable so that I can authenticate into an R studio instance. If I just put a username and password in plain text under environment it works fine.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: In your Dockerfile, the way you define your entrypoint make Docker search 'entry.sh' in the `PATH` where it's not. Try to use absolute path `ENTRYPOINT ["/entry.sh"]`

Comment: Can you give the command you use to create your image and the output?

Comment: And BTW, from what I understand from your entry.sh script, your secrets must contain 'USER=user' and 'PASSWORD=test123', not just the values. And you should not declare them as environment in your compose file.

Comment: hi I used the command docker build .

Comment: ENTRYPOINT ["/entry.sh"] Still does not solve the issue

Comment: Can you give the full docker build command? And also the error message you get?

Comment: BTW, are you launching a docker stack or docker-compose?